Using pdfrender makes text appear too thick when zoomed out
I'm using pdfrender to make \mathbb look thicker, but when I zoom out the pdf it appears much thicker than the rest of the text.


The first print is zoomed in, while the second one is zoomed out.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pdfrender, xcolor}
\newcommand{\N}{{\pdfrender{StrokeColor=black,TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.11pt} \ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}}


\begin{document}
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Let $n \in \N $
\end{document}

Is there a way to achieve a similar effect without this distortion at a lower zoom?
